# How can I make this YOLO image detection model to run the object detection on a ESP32 Cam live feed?

Tags: javascript, html, esp32, yolo, yolov8

For context, I am building a remote control surveillance car that runs on local network. I am using an ESP32 Camera for the project, and I want to implement the YOLO image detection AI to the camera feed. However, I don't think the ESP32 Camera is strong enough to process the AI files.

Hence, I am running the AI model on a different local server, and use iframe to get the html content of the ESP32 Cam inside the AI model HTML file itself. But the problem is, the object detection can run only on **video**, and the camera feed of the webcam is inside an **img** tag. So the image detection won't work.

I will provide the code -

HTML code of the AI Image Detection -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Object Detector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Iframe to embed ESP32-CAM HTML -->
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://192.168.1.3" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; border: none;"></iframe>
    <script src="object_detector.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Ip address src inside the iframe is the html webpage hosted by the ESP32 Camera.
The code for that -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
    .arrows {
      font-size:40px;
      color:red;
    }
    td.button {
      background-color:black;
      border-radius:25%;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px #888888;
    }
    td.button:active {
      transform: translate(5px,5px);
      box-shadow: none; 
    }

    .noselect {
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
         -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
           -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                      supported by Chrome and Opera */
    }

    .slidecontainer {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>
  
  </head>
  <body class="noselect" align="center" style="background-color:white">
     
    <!--h2 style="color: teal;text-align:center;">Wi-Fi Camera &#128663; Control</h2-->
    
    <table id="mainTable" style="width:400px;margin:auto;table-layout:fixed" CELLSPACING=10>
      <tr>
        <img id="cameraImage" src="" style="width:400px;height:250px"></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","1")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8679;</span></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","3")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8678;</span></td>
        <td class="button"></td>    
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","4")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8680;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","2")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8681;</span></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr/><tr/>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left"><b>Speed:</b></td>
        <td colspan=2>
         <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="150" class="slider" id="Speed" oninput='sendButtonInput("Speed",value)'>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>        
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left"><b>Light:</b></td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" class="slider" id="Light" oninput='sendButtonInput("Light",value)'>
          </div>
        </td>   
      </tr>
    </table>
  
    <script>
      var webSocketCameraUrl = "wss:\/\/" + window.location.hostname + "/Camera";
      var webSocketCarInputUrl = "wss:\/\/" + window.location.hostname + "/CarInput";      
      var websocketCamera;
      var websocketCarInput;
      
      function initCameraWebSocket() 
      {
        websocketCamera = new WebSocket(webSocketCameraUrl);
        websocketCamera.binaryType = 'blob';
        websocketCamera.onopen    = function(event){};
        websocketCamera.onclose   = function(event){setTimeout(initCameraWebSocket, 2000);};
        websocketCamera.onmessage = function(event)
        {
          var imageId = document.getElementById("cameraImage");
          imageId.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        };
      }
      
      function initCarInputWebSocket() 
      {
        websocketCarInput = new WebSocket(webSocketCarInputUrl);
        websocketCarInput.onopen    = function(event)
        {
          var speedButton = document.getElementById("Speed");
          sendButtonInput("Speed", speedButton.value);
          var lightButton = document.getElementById("Light");
          sendButtonInput("Light", lightButton.value);
        };
        websocketCarInput.onclose   = function(event){setTimeout(initCarInputWebSocket, 2000);};
        websocketCarInput.onmessage = function(event){};        
      }
      
      function initWebSocket() 
      {
        initCameraWebSocket ();
        initCarInputWebSocket();
      }

      function sendButtonInput(key, value) 
      {
        var data = key + "," + value;
        websocketCarInput.send(data);
      }
    
      window.onload = initWebSocket;
      document.getElementById("mainTable").addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
      });      
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

**This is the code where the camera streams** - `<img id="cameraImage" src="" style="width:400px;height:250px"></td>`

But the the AI only works on video element.

The full code for the AI image detector model - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/bstg2g7wzjv3fd8y79aa3/h?rlkey=h6y755t2whun86i3ze8acw70h&dl=0
Please note that the commented code inside the html file is the original code for the AI image detection, and it works on videos and webcam stream.

*(Also, I am aware that the object detection AI should be able to get content from inside the iframe, but I have not included the code as it was very messy)*

So, how can I make the AI image detection to work on img tag? Or if it's not possible, is there any workaround for it?

In case you need the arduino code for the ESP32 Cam - https://pastebin.com/Aam4FCmV

I hope my question is clear and please let me know if you need further details.